# How to aggregate data frame columns which basically contain the same information but are segregated because of different case sensitivity

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to to preprocess my data in a way that I can use some keywords as categorical variables. Problem is that some keywords have the same information but are not in one column because they are written differently from a case sensitive point of view. How can I aggregate these columns which only differ by there spelling regaridng capital letters or not?

```
#Creating dictionary
d = {
    "Recurrent Neural Network" : [1],
    "Recurrent neural network" : [1],
}
#Creating dataFrame with kind of duplicate columns
d_test = pd.DataFrame(d)



#How it should be 
d_new = {
    "Recurrent Neural Network" : [1,1]
}

d_test_new = pd.DataFrame(d_new)
```

Comment: You are right, the 's' shouldn't be there. I just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try something like this:

```py
cols_lower= pd.Index([x.lower() for x in d_test.columns])

new_d = {}
for col in set(cols_lower):  # iterate over unique column names (lowercase)
    logic = cols_lower == col
    if logic.sum() > 1:  # More than 1 column
        concat = d_test.iloc[:,logic].values.tolist()
        new_d[col] = concat
    else:
        new_d[col] = d_test.iloc[:,logic.argmax()].to_list()  # Original column

new_d = pd.DataFrame(new_d)
```

The final column names are lowercase. If you want them as a Title you can replace `new_d[col]` by `new_d[col.title()]`.